# Updating SQL database using VB.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I try to update database in MS SQL in ASP using VB.NET. This is my code. There is no error but the data in database are not updated

```
Dim cnConnect As New SqlConnection
    cnConnect.ConnectionString = conn.ConnectionString
    cnConnect.Open()
    Dim cm As New SqlCommand
    cm.CommandText = "UPDATE book SET name = '" & name.Text & "'
    WHERE idnum = '" & idno.Text & "';"
    cm.Connection = cnConnect
    cnConnect.Close()
```

Comment: A command needs to be executed to produce any result. Your code lacks a critical line: cm.ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: By the way, you've got this existing connection called conn - you could probably have used that as the connection to attach to the command, not needed to make a new connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed to execute the query. You may have to execute the query before closing the connection like this,

```
cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 3):

A command needs to be executed to produce any result.
You need to call **cm.ExecuteNonQuery.**
However your code has other problems.
The most dangerous one is the string concatenation of values to form an Sql Statement. This is a [well known problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) that allows hackers to mess with (or simply destroy) your database.
Apart from hacking, also a simple quote inside your *name* TextBox (like *McDonald's*) will break your code with a syntax error. (try it)
There is only one solution and it is: **Use Parameters**

```
Dim sqlText = "UPDATE book SET name = @name WHERE idnum = @num"
Using cnConnect = New SqlConnection(conn.ConnectionString)
Using cm = new SqlCommand(sqlText, cnConnect)
   cnConnect.Open()
   cm.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = name.Text
   cm.Parameters.Add("@num", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = idno.Text 
   cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
End Using
```

Also note how the Disposable objects used are enclosed in a Using block to allow the automatic destroy of the resources used by those objects at the closing of the Using block